# Speeding up RegionIntersection of multiple sets of rectangles

Tags: regions, computational-geometry, intersection

There is a set of disjoint rectangles `shadow` that change position over time.
I want to find their intersection with another set of small rectangles `BIPV` divided by a large rectangle.

[image: a set of disjoint rectangles] [image]

I want to find the intersection of the union of the first group of disjoint rectangles and each small rectangle in the second group of shapes. Since I need to calculate the results for different moments of the day, the `RegionIntersection` calculation takes a long time. In addition, I found that there are some moments when `RegionIntersection` fails to compute and quits the kernel.

Here is my input data:

```
dhcb=40*10^-3; dwcb=76*10^-3; wcell=0.156; hcell=0.156; 
m11=4; n11=9; lengthm=1.644; widthm=0.986; dhc=20*10^-3; dwc=70*10^-3; dair=0.22;
a = {Quantity[121.23806779711492`, "AngularDegrees"], 
  Quantity[121.94869445542565`, "AngularDegrees"], 
  Quantity[122.67177064556768`, "AngularDegrees"], 
  Quantity[123.40771442795332`, "AngularDegrees"], 
  Quantity[124.15695029004759`, "AngularDegrees"], 
  Quantity[124.91990874975208`, "AngularDegrees"], 
  Quantity[125.69702585837106`, "AngularDegrees"], 
  Quantity[126.48874259272147`, "AngularDegrees"], 
  Quantity[127.29550412528923`, "AngularDegrees"], 
  Quantity[128.11775896060843`, "AngularDegrees"], 
  Quantity[128.95595792541283`, "AngularDegrees"], 
  Quantity[129.81055299958817`, "AngularDegrees"], 
  Quantity[130.6819959744818`, "AngularDegrees"], 
  Quantity[131.57073692487887`, "AngularDegrees"], 
  Quantity[132.4772224808424`, "AngularDegrees"], 
  Quantity[133.40189388581388`, "AngularDegrees"], 
  Quantity[134.34518482776366`, "AngularDegrees"], 
  Quantity[135.3075190311038`, "AngularDegrees"], 
  Quantity[136.28930759823245`, "AngularDegrees"], 
  Quantity[137.29094609140742`, "AngularDegrees"], 
  Quantity[138.31281134798638`, "AngularDegrees"]};
b = {Quantity[11.272464553690103`, "AngularDegrees"], 
  Quantity[12.204318573361663`, "AngularDegrees"], 
  Quantity[13.129678952213057`, "AngularDegrees"], 
  Quantity[14.048116158223586`, "AngularDegrees"], 
  Quantity[14.959224582046756`, "AngularDegrees"], 
  Quantity[15.863330937231444`, "AngularDegrees"], 
  Quantity[16.75840049230896`, "AngularDegrees"], 
  Quantity[17.645003790579594`, "AngularDegrees"], 
  Quantity[18.52275211367755`, "AngularDegrees"], 
  Quantity[19.391253528306056`, "AngularDegrees"], 
  Quantity[20.25011026247351`, "AngularDegrees"], 
  Quantity[21.098916695549395`, "AngularDegrees"], 
  Quantity[21.937257792754796`, "AngularDegrees"], 
  Quantity[22.76470787153537`, "AngularDegrees"], 
  Quantity[23.580829624554497`, "AngularDegrees"], 
  Quantity[24.38517334919042`, "AngularDegrees"], 
  Quantity[25.17727635059265`, "AngularDegrees"], 
  Quantity[25.956662497578233`, "AngularDegrees"], 
  Quantity[26.722841919227953`, "AngularDegrees"], 
  Quantity[27.475310836473415`, "AngularDegrees"], 
  Quantity[28.21355152768885`, "AngularDegrees"]};
m = 21;
n = 46;
BIPV = ConstantArray[0, {m, n}];rs = ConstantArray[0, {m, n}];

 Table[
 BIPV[[4 (i - 1) + i + k, 4 (j - 1) + j + l]] = 
  Rectangle[{dwcb + (wcell + dwc)*(i - 1) + (wcell/4)*(k - 1), 
    dhcb + (hcell + dhc)*(j - 1) + (hcell/4)*(l - 1)}, {dwcb + 
     wcell/4 + (wcell + dwc)*(i - 1) + (wcell/4)*(k - 1), 
    dhcb + hcell/4 + (hcell + dhc)*(j - 1) + (hcell/4)*(l - 1)}];
 BIPV[[4 (i - 1) + i + k, 5 q + 1]] = 
  Rectangle[{dwcb + (wcell + dwc)*(i - 1) + (wcell/4)*(k - 1), 
    dhcb + hcell + (hcell + dhc)*(q - 1)}, {dwcb + 
     wcell/4 + (wcell + dwc)*(i - 1) + (wcell/4)*(k - 1), 
    dhcb + (hcell + dhc)*q}];
 BIPV[[1 + (m - 1)*(o - 1), 4 (j - 1) + j + l]] = 
  Rectangle[{(widthm - dwcb)*(o - 1), 
    dhcb + (hcell + dhc)*(j - 1) + (hcell/4)*(l - 
        1)}, {dwcb + (widthm - dwcb)*(o - 1), 
    dhcb + hcell/4 + (hcell + dhc)*(j - 1) + (hcell/4)*(l - 1)}];
 BIPV[[1 + (m - 1)*(o - 1), 5 q + 1]] = 
  Rectangle[{(widthm - dwcb)*(o - 1), 
    dhcb + hcell + (hcell + dhc)*(q - 1)}, {dwcb + (widthm - 
        dwcb)*(o - 1), dhcb + (hcell + dhc)*q}];
 BIPV[[4 (i - 1) + i + k, 1 + (n - 1)*(o - 1)]] = 
  Rectangle[{dwcb + (wcell + dwc)*(i - 1) + (wcell/4)*(k - 
        1), (lengthm - dhcb)*(o - 1)}, {dwcb + 
     wcell/4 + (wcell + dwc)*(i - 1) + (wcell/4)*(k - 1), 
    dhcb + (lengthm - dhcb)*(o - 1)}];
 BIPV[[5 p + 1, 1 + (n - 1)*(o - 1)]] = 
  Rectangle[{dwcb + 
     wcell + (wcell + dwc)*(p - 1), (lengthm - dhcb)*(o - 
       1)}, {dwcb + (wcell + dwc)*p, dhcb + (lengthm - dhcb)*(o - 1)}];
 BIPV[[5 p + 1, 4 (j - 1) + j + l]] = 
  Rectangle[{dwcb + wcell + (wcell + dwc)*(p - 1), 
    dhcb + (hcell + dhc)*(j - 1) + (hcell/4)*(l - 
        1)}, {dwcb + (wcell + dwc)*p, 
    dhcb + hcell/4 + (hcell + dhc)*(j - 1) + (hcell/4)*(l - 1)}];
 BIPV[[5 p + 1, 5 q + 1]] = 
  Rectangle[{dwcb + wcell + (wcell + dwc)*(p - 1), 
    dhcb + hcell + (hcell + dhc)*(q - 1)}, {dwcb + (wcell + dwc)*p, 
    dhcb + (hcell + dhc)*q}];
 , {i, 1, m11}, {j, 1, n11}, {k, 1, 4}, {l, 1, 4}, {q, 1, 
  n11 - 1}, {o, 1, 2}, {p, 1, m11 - 1}];
BIPV[[1, 1]] = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {dwcb, dhcb}];
BIPV[[m, 1]] = Rectangle[{widthm - dwcb, 0}, {widthm, dhcb}];
BIPV[[1, n]] = Rectangle[{0, lengthm - dhcb}, {dwcb, lengthm}];
BIPV[[m, n]] = 
  Rectangle[{widthm - dwcb, lengthm - dhcb}, {widthm, lengthm}];
```

And I write:

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 Table[
   PVs = 
    RegionUnion[
     Flatten[Table[
       Rectangle[{dwcb + (wcell + dwc)*(i - 1) + dair*Tan[a[[ll]]], 
         dhcb + (hcell + dhc)*(j - 1) - 
          dair*Tan[b[[ll]]]/Abs[Cos[a[[ll]]]]}, {dwcb + 
          wcell + (wcell + dwc)*(i - 1) + dair*Tan[a[[ll]]], 
         dhcb + hcell + (hcell + dhc)*(j - 1) - 
          dair*Tan[b[[ll]]]/Abs[Cos[a[[ll]]]]}]
       , {i, 1, m11}, {j, 1, n11}]]];
   hf = dair*Tan[b[[ll]]];
   wf = dair*Tan[a[[ll]]];
   If[wf < 0, 
    frames = 
     RegionUnion[Rectangle[{0, lengthm - hf}, {widthm, lengthm}], 
      Rectangle[{widthm + wf, 0}, {widthm, lengthm}]], 
    frames = 
     RegionUnion[Rectangle[{0, lengthm - hf}, {widthm, lengthm}], 
      Rectangle[{0, 0}, {wf, lengthm}]]];
   shadow = DiscretizeRegion[RegionUnion[PVs, frames]];
sh[i0_, j0_] := Module[{i = i0, j = j0},
   (RegionMeasure[RegionIntersection[shadow, BIPV[[i, j]]], 2])/
    RegionMeasure[BIPV[[i, j]], 2]];
Table[rs[[i, j]] = sh[i, j], {i, 1, m}, {j, 1, n}];
   rss=RegionIntersection[shadow, 
    Rectangle[{0, 0}, {widthm, lengthm}]];, {ll, 1, 21}];]
```

I've found that the `Table` loop aborts and exits the kernel regardless of whether I'm calculating the intersection `rs` of non-intersecting rectangles `shadow` and small rectangles `BIPV`, or the intersection `rss` of non-intersecting rectangles `shadow`  and large rectangles.
I've looked through related posts and tried `Rationalize`, `Implicit`, and `DiscretizeRegion` but none of them work. I can only split the first set of graphs into two types (PVs and frames) and intersect them with the second set of graphs, but this takes longer to compute. I tried to use parallel arithmetic, but I found that the function for parallel arithmetic does not include `RegionIntersection`.

[image] [image]